# Is returning reference to an element in a growing vector bad practice?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference, move

I'm experiencing a strange memory bug (segfault). After some code review I found that I'm passing a pointer to self (`this`) to a member value inside a class, which itself is inside a vector and it's about to change its address. Then (possibly) vector grows and the pointer that just passed become invalid.

My understanding is `std::vector` is supposed to move its content in memory, since its guaranteed to be continues, right? I thought that I can overcome this by passing a const reference instead of pointer (passing `*this`). But I'm having same segfault. I can't see why references can become invalid just as pointers do! The situation can be summarized like this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(): x(new Bar(*this)){}
    Foo(Foo&&);
    Foo& operator=(Foo&&)
private:
    // some heavy to move data
    Bar* x;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(const Foo& foo): instance(foo){}
private:
    const Foo& instance;
};

std::vector<Zoo> vec;
// Do some stuff on vec, then x->instance become invalid. Why?
```

Comment: _'But I'm having same segfault.'_ This clearly invalidates doing so as _good practice_!

Comment: Where is `Zoo` declared and what exactly are you doing with the `vector<Zoo>`? Yes, code returning element in a growing vector by reference may blow up on the first internal memory reallocation happening in the vector (at sizes 0, 1, 2, 4, etc. by default).

Comment: You can potentially deal with this by reserving  enough space in the vector that it never has to grow, but generally what you've described is a time bomb waiting to go off.

Comment: *Is returning reference to an element in a growing vector bad practice?* It is only if you storing that reference for future use. However, nothing in your posted code tells where and how you are doing this.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Reserving enough space is not an option for me. I'm going to use `std::list` (with linear access time!)

Comment: @RSahu Yes I'm storing the reference for the future. Actually after parsers have made the data structures, the algorithm is supposed to operate on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a vector needs to reallocate its storage, the objects that lived at the "old" location are deleted after they've been copied (or moved into) the new storage. The move doesn't "teleport" an object to a new location, it's still creating a new object in the new location.

The reference you're holding references the "old" object that has been deleted by the vector reallocation operation. Using that reference will lead to undefined behavior. Same as the pointer case. You can't store an iterator either, those are invalidated too.

You'll need to find another way to keep track of that element. Exactly how you do that depends on what you're trying to do. Sometimes just keeping an index is enough.